# truecrypt container not syncing to google drive

Tags: truecrypt, google-drive

I have a truecrypt container located in my Google drive. I mount the container, add a few files and then dismount it. However, the file won't sync as the timestamps remains the same. To prove that I'm right, I've downloaded the container file from Google Drive's web interface and I don't see the new files I've put before.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Disable the *"Preserve modification timestamp of file containers"* option in TrueCrypt Preferences.